# How to modify/copy and edit a filter in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I would like to take a filter (in this case, the mosaic) and use it as a base for another filter. I want my end result to be the mosaic, but without the borders between "tiles". I want to know if there is a way to customize the filter beyond the dialog box.

Is it possible to copy the code and put it into my scripts folder for editing?

Comment: As long as you don't need to change the core of the filter itself, you can invoke it through script-fu or python-fu and building a composite filter.

Comment: Yeah, please elaborate on what you want to do - and give us the whole, not a single step. Often, the initial description of what users think they have to do is waaaaaay misleading.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Does this edit help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't put this filter's code into your scripts directory and change it.

GIMP's mosaic is written in C and needs to be compiled and linked into a platform-specific binary in order to be usable. And as a plug-in rather than a script, that binary then belongs into the plug-ins folder.

You can change the source code of it and do that, but you may have to acquire the skills to do so first.

Have a look:
https://git.gnome.org/browse/gimp/tree/plug-ins/common/mosaic.c?h=gimp-2-8